# Amazon S3 Upload with metadata?

Tags: amazon-s3, mp3, metadata

I'm trying to upload several thousand song files to Amazon S3.  All of these files have metadata already associated with them such as author, genre, etc.  Is there any way to preserve this metadata so that it appears in the S3 Management Console when the files are uploaded?

If not, can you suggest a way to easily add this metadata to the songs?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a collection of metadata "key" "value".
Then you give your request this collection as parameter.

In C# it's

```cs
 InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initiateMultipartUploadRequest =
                new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest()
                    .WithBucketName(_transferUtility.BucketName)
                    .WithKey(_key)
                    .WithMetaData(collection);
```

It can be any other Request.

This MetaData is shown in S3 Management Console as metadata with a Prefix.